Cannot enable usb ethernet gadget on u-boot with pi-zero-2-w
I am following this tutorial to establish tftp on my rpi: https://bootlin.com/blog/tftp-nfs-booting-beagle-bone-black-wireless-pocket-beagle/. But I cannot make u-boot start usb ethernet gadget.
I have enabled this additional lines in .config:

CONFIG_USB_HOST_ETHER=y 
CONFIG_USB_ETHER_LAN78XX=y 
CONFIG_USB_ETHER_SMSC95XX=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_MANUFACTURER="U-Boot"
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VENDOR_NUM=0x2E8A
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_PRODUCT_NUM=0x000E
CONFIG_CI_UDC=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW=2
CONFIG_USB_ETHER=y
CONFIG_USB_ETH_RNDIS=y
CONFIG_USBNET_DEV_ADDR="f8:dc:7a:00:00:02"
CONFIG_USBNET_HOST_ADDR="f8:dc:7a:00:00:01"
CONFIG_USB_FUNCTION_MASS_STORAGE=y

I have set these u-boot env virables:

ipaddr 192.168.0.100 
serverip 192.168.0.1 
ethprime usb_ether 
usbnet_devaddr f8:dc:7a:00:00:02 
usbnet_hostaddr f8:dc:7a:00:00:01 

Here are usb infos from u-boot shell:

However, inside u-boot shell when I try to ping 192.168.0.1 it says: no ethernet found.
I enabled usb mass storage gadget also, to test if it will work.
The command: 

ums 1 mmc 0:1

Results in:

UMS: LUN 0, dev mmc 0, hwpart 0, sector 0x800, count 0x32000 
USB DWC2 
<UEI f86678a4> (this line repeats infinetly) 

What can I do in this situtation? Is it even possible to establish usb gadget functionality on pi-zero-2-w during u-boot ?

Pi Zero 2 W does not have an ethernet port

@jsotola I am writing about usb gadget.
